# 'duplicate content' on several different pages

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, duplicate-content

I've a website with 6 pages identified as 'duplicate content' because they are very similar. This pages looks similar because are the same but it show some pictures, a few, about the product category that's why every page look alike each to each other but they are not 'exactly' the same. So, it's any way to indicate to Google that the content is not duplicated?

I guess it's been marked as duplicate because the code is 90% or more the same on 6 pages.

I've been reviewing the 'canonical' method but I think is not appropriated here as the content is not the same.

Any advice (that is not add more content)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but you can't really have Google index pages that it doesn't want to index. Luckily in this instance, it's giving you reasons as to why it won't index those pages. Much of the time it doesn't give webmasters a reason at all.

Because your pages are so similar, Google has marked them as duplicate.

You really have just a few options here:

1. Use the rel=canonical tag
2. Add NOINDEX to the header
3. Leave it as is
4. 301 redirect the duplicate pages to the canonical page
5. Add more diversified content to the pages that you are trying to rank

I know the options presented aren't necessarily what you're looking for. But I don't think you'll find a correct answer that does. I know you don't want to add more content to the pages, but great content is how you get to rank your site on Google. You can do it. I hope I was helpful.

Comment: yes, finally I will add more content to the pages. Thanks.